# Validar inicial en Mayuscula

Tags: validación, pseint

disculpen, necesito validar nombre, apellido, pero con la inicial en mayúscula, he intentado hacer una comprobación en donde "mientras" nombre sea mayor o igual a 'a' y el nombre será menor o igual a 'z' hacer que se le muestre el mensaje de error hasta que el usuario ingrese su nombre con la inicial en mayúscula, sin embargo, al hacer esto, el código pregunta de manera infinita y no respeta la inicial que usuario ingrese.
agradecería sus consejos.
saludos

```
Funcion comprobacion
Mientras datosUsuario >= 'a' Y datosUsuario <= 'z' Hacer
    Escribir 'mal'
    Leer datosUsuario
FinMientras
```

FinFuncion

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?